# Verify hostname on SSL Certificate - Android

Tags: android, ssl

I am using `HttpsURLConnection` to connect to a server. I implemented the verify method of `HostnameVerifie`r interface to verify the hostname.

**This is my code.**

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        boolean allow = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier().verify(hostname,session);
        return allow;
    }
};
```

Is this enough to verify hostnames? As I do not have enough knowledge on **SSL**, **CA** etc I am unable to decide.

If this is not sufficient, How do I verify hostnames on SSL Certificates in Android?

**How do I test this current piece of code? I have never used a hacking tool.**

Comment: you can use library [Memorizing TrustManager](https://github.com/ge0rg/MemorizingTrustManager/wiki/Integration)

Comment: NO, I don't want any 3rd party library.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? hostname verification is a necessary but not sufficient condition to perform a TLS handshake, for example